# can't debug C with makefile in vscode

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, makefile, vscode-debugger

I need a way to debug a C program consisting of multi C files with the makefile in vscode, when I debug the program using the wingw32-make command in the tasks.json , the program run directly without stoping at the breakpoints, but when using the gcc command in the tasks.json the breakpoints can be arrived. I am confused. 
Forgive my ignorance, any response would be greatly appreciated!

below is my code

**heada.h**

```
#ifndef PRACTICES_MYFUNC0A_H
#define PRACTICES_MYFUNC0A_H

enum steerwheel  {square, circle};
typedef struct {
    int wheels;
    enum steerwheel sw;
} Car;

Car * getCar(int, enum steerwheel);

#endif //PRACTICES_MYFUNC0A_H
```

**MainTest.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include "funcha.h"

int main() {
    Car *car = getCar(4, square);
    int i;
    printf("%d,%d\n",car->wheels, car->sw);
    scanf("%d",&i);
    printf("%d\n", i);
    free(car);
    getchar();
}
```

**MyFunc01.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include "funcha.h"

Car * getCar(int wheels, enum steerwheel sw) {
    Car *car = malloc(sizeof(Car));
    car->wheels = wheels;
    car->sw = sw;
    return car;
}
```

**Makefile**

```
MainTest: MainTest.o myFunc01.o funcha.h
    gcc -o MainTest MainTest.o myFunc01.o
myFunc01.o: myFunc01.c funcha.h
    gcc -c myFunc01.c
MainTest.o: MainTest.c funcha.h
    gcc -c MainTest.c
.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm MainTest myFunc01.o MainTest.o
```

and the .vscode foloer's file is below:
**launch.json**

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) 启动",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "D:\\work_softwares\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "为 gdb 启用整齐打印",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "makerun"
        }

    ]
}
```

**tasks.json**

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "makerun",
            // this manner can arrived at the breakpoints。 why ???????
            "command": "D:\\work_softwares\\mingw64\\bin\\mingw32-make.exe",
            "args": [
                "-C",
                "${workspaceFolder}",
                "MainTest"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "D:\\work_softwares\\mingw64\\bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "notmakerun",
            // this manner can arrived at the breakpoints。
            "command": "D:\\work_softwares\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${workspaceFolder}\\*.c",
                "-o",
                "${workspaceFolder}\\MainTest.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "D:\\work_softwares\\mingw64\\bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": []
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your Makefile compilation command, you're not passing debug flags, like `-g` or `-ggdb` to the gcc invocation. So you can't put a breakpoint in the build generated via Makefile.

But in tasks.json, specifically the task labelled with `notmakerun`, you are passing `-g` flag. So build will be generated with debug symbols, and so you can debug it.

In a nutshell, try adding `-g` into the all of the `gcc` commands in the Makefile